# What is the Difference between SQL and SQL*Plus?

Tags: sql, sqlplus

What is the Difference between SQL and SQL*Plus?

Answer (score 15):

SQL* Plus is a command line tool proprietary to Oracle. You can send SQL queries to the server using the tool. It can also help you format the result of a query.

You should get a good head start on SQL*Plus here http://www.comp.nus.edu.sg/~ooibc/courses/sql/sqlplus.htm

SQL is the query language that is used to communicate with Oracle server to access and modify the data.

cheers

Answer (score 11):

SQL is a language, SQL*Plus is a tool.

Answer (score 4):

SQL*Plus is an Oracle product that you use to run SQL and PL/SQL statements.

Answer (score 2):

SQL*Plus, the primary interface to the Oracle Database server, provides a powerful yet easy-to-use environment for querying, defining, and controlling data. SQL*Plus delivers a full implementation of Oracle SQL and PL/SQL, along with a rich set of extensions. The exceptional scalability of the Oracle Database, coupled with the object-relational technology of SQL*Plus, allows you to develop your complex datatypes and objects using Oracle's integrated systems solution.
From Oracle.com (http://www.oracle.com/technology/tech/sql_plus/index.html)

Comment: This is brazen even by marketingspeak standards. I can't see anyone outside Oracle's PR department seriously describing SQL*Plus as "a powerful yet easy-to-use environment", seeing as how it's virtually impossible to do any serious work in Oracle without recourse to a tool such as TOAD, PL/SQL Developer or Oracle SQL Developer

Comment: It seemed like a pretty powerful tool to me when I learned it - in 1988. I kind of like the way it hasn't really changed at all in the intervening 21 years.

Answer (score 1):

sql*plus is a character based interactive tool,rhat runs in a GUI invironment. It is loaded on the client machine .